# MySQL order by date and priority

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a web page which has news data in one table.

In many cases I use following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY insertDate DESC
```

to order.

```
ID|priority|insertDate
1 |NULL    |2012-09-16
2 |NULL    |2012-09-17
3 |NULL    |2012-09-18
5 |NULL    |2012-09-19
5 |NULL    |2012-09-20
4 |1       |2010-05-10 - this is way back in the future
```

But user wants to prioritize 1 news. And if I use

```
 SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY priority ASC ,insertDate DESC
```

It doesn't work correctly, how do I must use ORDER to get result

```
ID|priority|insertDate
4 |1       |2010-05-10
1 |NULL    |2012-09-16
2 |NULL    |2012-09-17
3 |NULL    |2012-09-18
5 |NULL    |2012-09-19
5 |NULL    |2012-09-20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to set a valid value to Null priority rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY 
   coalesce(priority,0) ASC ,
   insertDate DESC
```

**Edited**

Re-reading your question I see that right order is DESC and not ASC:

```
   coalesce(priority,0) DESC ,
```

Also, notice @yshavit comment. To improve performance you can split query in two selects first one with not null values.

Remember than when you create this new field you [can set to it a default value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html), this will avoid `coalesce` and `union`:

```
data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
```

Comment: Note that this means the query won't be able to use indexes for ordering. If you want all of the NULLs last instead of first, it may be better to have two SELECTs, one where priority is not null and one where priority is null, and UNION them. I can't try it now, but I imagine that would be able to use indexes.

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY 
   coalesce(priority,0) DESC,
   insertDate DESC

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY 
   if(priority IS NULL,'0',priority) ASC ,
   insertDate DESC;
```